# How to iterate over characters that does not exists? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

I have three text strings, each with different lengths and stored in a list, such as `['food', 'entertainment', 'auto']`.

Now, I need to display them vertically in console, something like:

```
f e a  
o n u  
o t t  
d e o  
  r  
  t  
  a  
  i  
  n  
  m  
  e  
  n  
  t
```

For which I intended to do this:

```py
result = ''
category_names = ['food', 'entertainment', 'auto']
longest_category_name = len(max(category_names, key=len))

for l in range(longest_category_name):
  result += f"{category_names[0][l]}{category_names[1][l]}{category_names[2][l]}\n"
```

However I run into the obvious `IndexError: string index out of range` error, but my question is, so how could I do this and have python ignore those non-existent characters?

**PS.** I thought about doing a one-line if but I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Comment: You can use longest zip available in itertools. checkout the documentation for https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: `import itertools

result = ''
category_names = ['food', 'entertainment', 'auto']
longest_category_name = len(max(category_names, key=len))

lines = itertools.zip_longest(*category_names, fillvalue = " ")

for line in lines:
    print(*line)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(l) for l in zip_longest(*category_names, fillvalue=' ')))
f e a
o n u
o t t
d e o
  r  
  t  
  a  
  i  
  n  
  m  
  e  
  n  
  t
```